# When does a screenreader read image alt text?

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers

Please correct me if I am wrong, but usually screen reader navigation works by pressing the tab key, and usually you do not have (or need) tab-able images. Therefore, when is the alt text actually useful to the screen reader?

I have seen examples where the screen reader reads things when pointed/selected by mouse (mostly for testing), but I am not sure if that is a practical usage.

(Another scenario that comes to mind is link images where the alt text might be used for link description.)

Please help me with more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> usually screenreader navigation works by pressing tab key

Typically only interactive items - links, buttons, and the like - are accessible by tabbing. But screenreader users need to be able to access *all* content on the page - not just the interactive items. Think of how useless a wikipedia page would be if you could only read out the links on it, and none of the content.

Screenreaders generally provide a set of tools and commands for navigating a web page:

- The simplest approach is to move linearly through the page, item by item. This will cover everything: non-interactive items, interactive items, text, images, everything!
- The user can also navigate between items of a similar type - from one list item to the next, or from one table to the next, or from one image to the next
- There are generally also commands to navigate the heading structure (H1...H6).
- Users can also search for specific text on the page, and then continue reading or exploring from there.

Check out this [list of shortcuts for common screenreaders](https://dequeuniversity.com/screenreaders/survival-guide) from accessibility specialists Deque.

Several screenreaders intercept and capture most keyboard input while the user is using them: if you're using JAWS or NVDA, for example, hitting the down arrow key causes the screenreader to move to the next item instead of causing the browser to scroll down. Likewise, hitting H causes the screenreader to move to the next heading - the browser never sees that keypress. (If you tab to an input field, however, the screenreaders will let the input go through.) On the Mac, the VoiceOver screenreader instead uses keyboard modifiers for its commands - or example, Control+Option+RightArrow moves to the next item.

Using a screenreader to navigate and read a page is perhaps a surprisingly interactive experience: you're not just listening to what the screenreader is reading out (or equivalent if using Braille), but using commands to tell it where to navigate next. A user might start off reading down through the initial part of the page to see what's there, then switch to heading navigation to see what the overall page structure is and find a specific section, then read through that item by item. If the user is familiar with a page, they might use the search command to find some well-known piece of text and jump straight there.

This isn't all that different than how sighted users might view a page: visually scanning the top level structure, reading the headings, and then reading a particular section. But whereas most sighted users take this process for granted, when using a screenreader, you have to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

> Please correct me if i am wrong, but usually screenreader navigation works by pressing tab key, and usually you do not have (or need) tab-able images

Yes this is wrong.

WebAIM publish the list of shortcuts for [NVDA](http://webaim.org/resources/shortcuts/nvda) or [JAWS](http://webaim.org/resources/shortcuts/jaws)

The `tab` key is only used to "Navigate to Next form Control".

You have different shortcuts to read the text, and the alternative text will be spoken when reading an image.